# Hibernate Internal Query Creation for CRUD

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I m new to hibernate framework and wanted to learn how hibernate works internally.

I have read few books 'hibernate made easy' and 'java persistence with hibernate'. I have ideas about how to configure relationship between objects, for e.g. (onetomany,many to many, inheritance, hql and all).

one thing which I m not able to understand, how hibernate creates query internally when I do CRUD operation. If I make show_sql=true, its printing the SQL, which hibernate creates and executes against the database.

Is there any possible easy way to understand hibernate internal query creation by reading books? is there any portal or books which cover hibernate query creation for relationships?

or do I need to debug the source code and understand what hibernate is doing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no book to cover Hibernate internals, but you can start from [AbstractEntityPersister](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/persister/entity/AbstractEntityPersister.java) as that's where the CRUD operations are handled.